# create a table with variable name (sqlite3)

Tags: python, sqlite

i want to create a table in sqlite3 with python put when i change number1 the name of table to the name of variable make the name of variable the name of table not the value in variable

```
db.execute("create table if not exists number1 (ID integer primary key autoincrement, item text, quantity integer,price_per_once integer, total integer)")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should consider that if the table name comes from user input, you will need additional code to protect against SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate a variable:

```
db.execute("create table if not exists " + table_name + " (ID integer primary key autoincrement, item text, quantity integer,price_per_once integer, total integer)")
```

Although if you're creating lots of tables with the same stucture, there's probably a better way to design your schema. Whatever the difference is between all these tables, it should probably just be a column in the table.

Comment: show me this error db.execute("create table if not exists " + NameVariable + " (ID integer primary key autoincrement, item text, quantity integer,price_per_once integer, total integer)")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "1": syntax error

Comment: sorry sorry i know the error and resolved it thank you

Comment: `1` is not a valid table name.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like this:

```
db.execute("create table " + tableNameVariable + " (...)")
```

Comment: show me this error db.execute("create table if not exists " + NameVariable + " (ID integer primary key autoincrement, item text, quantity integer,price_per_once integer, total integer)")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "1": syntax error

Comment: sorry sorry i know the error and resolved it thank you